# How to calculate the enclosed area between the curve $y=\ln{x}$ and the 'x' axis between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$

Tags: graphing-functions, area, curves

Any assistance on calculating: the enclosed area $(A)$ between the curve $y=ln(x)$ and the $x-axis$ between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ then to draw the graph of the function?

I know the equation will be something along the lines of:

$$A = \int_1^2{|ln(x)-0|} = \int_1^2{ln(x)}$$

Then:

$$\large\int{ln(x)} = xln(x)-x+C$$

$$\large A = (xln(x)-x)|_1^2 = 2(ln(2))-2-[1(ln(1))-1] = ?$$

But somehow my calculations seem incorrect and I am not sure how to proceed into graphing the function.

Comment: You went from $2 \log 2$ to $2(1)$. For reference: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+x+axis+and+ln(x)+from+x%3D1+to+x%3D2

Comment: What is the base of your logarithm? If it is $e$, then $\ln(2)\neq 2$

Comment: Isn't 2 the base of the natural logarithm?

Comment: @Nitin isn't $\log{2}$ the same as finding the value of x in $2^x=2$ from which, if I remember correctly: $\log_a{x}=N$ means $a^N=x$?

Comment: [No, it very definitely isn't](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

Comment: @Nij Sorry but my math is not too good. Then how would I proceed?

Comment: @OmariCelestine the base of the natural logarithm is $e \approx 2.71828$. One way to \emph{define} $e$ is the unique number such that $\int_1^e \frac{1}{x} \;\mathrm{d}x = 1$.

Comment: @Nitin thanks, I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went wrong when you changed base

$$\int_1^2ln(x)dx=\int_1^21\cdot ln(x)dx$$
Integration by parts leads you to

$$x\cdot ln(x)-\int x\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$x\cdot ln(x)-x$$

plug in the x values to get an answer of 0.386

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln+x+from+1+to+2